# Upside down ground correction?

Tags: physics, mathematics, platformer, pico-8

How would you go about making ground correction for a platformer but upside down(reversed gravity)? I used this formula: `P.Y+=(P.Y-2)%8-1` but the character just keeps bumping up and down like a pogo stick.

By ground correction I mean checking if the player is inside a solid tile while falling and moving him up (or down in my case) until he isn't.

if pd.dy<0 then
pd.f=true
pd.g=false
pd.j=false
if col_map(pd,"up",1) then
pd.f=false
pd.dy=0
pd.g=true
pd.y+=(pd.y-1)%8
end
elseif pd.dy>0 then
pd.j=true
if col_map(pd,"down",1) then
pd.dy=0
end
end

Comment: I'd recommend showing us this code in the context of where it appears in your program.

Comment: if pd.dy<0 then
  pd.f=true
  pd.g=false
  pd.j=false  
  
  if col_map(pd,"up",1) then
    pd.f=false
    pd.dy=0
    pd.g=true
    pd.y+=(pd.y-1)%8
  end
elseif pd.dy>0 then
  pd.j=true
  if col_map(pd,"down",1) then
    pd.dy=0
  end
end

Comment: You've probably noticed that code doesn't read well in comments. Always use the edit link at the bottom of your question to ensure important information like this is part of your question and formatted correctly, not hidden in a comment. See the [help] if you need formatting guidance.